# secure videos url not playing in jw player react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwplayer

I am trying to play signed url videos from JW Player in my React JS application using **reactreact-jw-player** library. After enabling the **Secure Video URLs** in JW player dashboard, no video is shown on the player, but as soon I disable this settings, the video is available to be played.

I tried to pass license key like below in my code, but still not working. Is there any thing I am doing wrong or any step that I am missing to set the JW Player in my react application.

```
<ReactJWPlayer
  playerId="4t00MwmP"
  playerScript="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/4t00MwmP.js"
  playlist={`https://cdn.jwplayer.com/v2/media/${mediaId}`}
  controls={false}
  licenseKey="+1bANyiZkaja12nPS2yV8ky+2NgQqilQmMg3/************/*********="
  isAutoPlay={false}             
  />
```